# How determine fault StoryBoard

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

The initial problem is enough known - "Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance".

There are many questions here in SO about it but all the solutions are more fixes or crutches. And most of questions are linked to concrete part of code.

Also there are few topics about this problem with possible causes:
https://wpftutorial.net/DebuggingAnimations.html
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2006/09/25/tip-cannot-animate-on-an-immutable-object-instance/

I have huge corporate app where a have hundreds styles and storyboards. I can't disable them step by step and it's painstaking work to looking for problem part of code.

I look at these bug not from side of looking for in many xamls but from side of loging. I tried to research info in InvalidOperationException that is raised but there is no useful info like control place in xaml or smth else.
Also one idea is to create class inherited from Storyboard and to override methods.
But there is no methods to override.

Can someone propose how to log the internality of storyboard or other class that is responsible of animation?

Comment: As I wrote I can't determine problem part of xaml and so can't provide example and certainly I can't upload sources. That's why I ask the way of loging all of storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

At last I found sulution.
You should add classes: listener to animation, AttachedProperty and custom StoryBoard.

```
public static class TriggerTracing
{
    static TriggerTracing()
    {
        // Initialise WPF Animation tracing and add a TriggerTraceListener
        PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
        PresentationTraceSources.AnimationSource.Listeners.Clear();
        PresentationTraceSources.AnimationSource.Listeners.Add(new TriggerTraceListener());
        PresentationTraceSources.AnimationSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;
    }

    #region TriggerName attached property

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the trigger name for the specified trigger. This will be used
    /// to identify the trigger in the debug output.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trigger">The trigger.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetTriggerName(TriggerBase trigger)
    {
        return (string)trigger.GetValue(TriggerNameProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the trigger name for the specified trigger. This will be used
    /// to identify the trigger in the debug output.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trigger">The trigger.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static void SetTriggerName(TriggerBase trigger, string value)
    {
        trigger.SetValue(TriggerNameProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggerNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "TriggerName",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(TriggerTracing),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    #endregion

    #region TraceEnabled attached property

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indication whether trace is enabled for the specified trigger.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trigger">The trigger.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool GetTraceEnabled(TriggerBase trigger)
    {
        return (bool)trigger.GetValue(TraceEnabledProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a value specifying whether trace is enabled for the specified trigger
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trigger"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public static void SetTraceEnabled(TriggerBase trigger, bool value)
    {
        trigger.SetValue(TraceEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TraceEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "TraceEnabled",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TriggerTracing),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnTraceEnabledChanged));

    private static void OnTraceEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var triggerBase = d as EventTrigger;

        if (triggerBase == null)
            return;

        if (!(e.NewValue is bool))
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            // insert dummy story-boards which can later be traced using WPF animation tracing

            var storyboard = new TriggerTraceStoryboard(triggerBase, TriggerTraceStoryboardType.Enter);
            triggerBase.Actions.Insert(0, new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = storyboard });

            //storyboard = new TriggerTraceStoryboard(triggerBase, TriggerTraceStoryboardType.Exit);
            //triggerBase.ExitActions.Insert(0, new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = storyboard });
        }
        else
        {
            // remove the dummy storyboards
            //foreach (TriggerActionCollection actionCollection in new[] { triggerBase.EnterActions, triggerBase.ExitActions })
            foreach (TriggerActionCollection actionCollection in new[] { triggerBase.Actions })
            {
                foreach (TriggerAction triggerAction in actionCollection)
                {
                    BeginStoryboard bsb = triggerAction as BeginStoryboard;

                    if (bsb != null && bsb.Storyboard != null && bsb.Storyboard is TriggerTraceStoryboard)
                    {
                        actionCollection.Remove(bsb);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private enum TriggerTraceStoryboardType
    {
        Enter, Exit
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A dummy storyboard for tracing purposes
    /// </summary>
    private class TriggerTraceStoryboard : Storyboard
    {
        public TriggerTraceStoryboardType StoryboardType { get; private set; }
        public TriggerBase TriggerBase { get; private set; }

        public TriggerTraceStoryboard(TriggerBase triggerBase, TriggerTraceStoryboardType storyboardType)
        {
            TriggerBase = triggerBase;
            StoryboardType = storyboardType;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A custom tracelistener.
    /// </summary>
    private class TriggerTraceListener : TraceListener
    {
        public override void TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            base.TraceEvent(eventCache, source, eventType, id, format, args);

            if (format.StartsWith("Storyboard has begun;"))
            {
                TriggerTraceStoryboard storyboard = args[1] as TriggerTraceStoryboard;
                if (storyboard != null)
                {
                    // add a breakpoint here to see when your trigger has been
                    // entered or exited

                    // the element being acted upon
                    object targetElement = args[5];

                    // the namescope of the element being acted upon
                    INameScope namescope = (INameScope)args[7];

                    TriggerBase triggerBase = storyboard.TriggerBase;
                    string triggerName = GetTriggerName(storyboard.TriggerBase);

                    var str = "";
                    var element = targetElement as DependencyObject;
                    while (element != null)
                    {
                        str += element.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                        element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
                    }

                    LoggingInfrastructure.DefaultLogger.Log(...);
                }
            }
        }

        public override void Write(string message)
        {
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
        }
    }
```

Then you could add property to xaml where you need:

```
<EventTrigger Ui:TriggerTracing.TriggerName="CopyTextBlockStyle PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"  
 Ui:TriggerTracing.TraceEnabled="True"  RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```